# I would like to know, is there any tool (is it possible) to create analytics dashboard similar to Youtube Studio for an OTT platform

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Am working on an OTT platform for that I need to build an analytics dashboard similar to YouTube Studio which must includes most watched content, watch time, content views, live users count etc. So my question is there any tool available to achieve this, if not can someone guide me how can I build this (what are the tools/technologies required)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use Google Data Studio. In the data studio, you can import your analytics data and create some dashboards for reports. actually, they have a youtube dashboard as a template maybe you wanna lookout.

ı think data studio is better than analytics. because in google analytics there are so many data and some of them not useful for other companies so in data studio you can put your data wherever you want.

you can learn easily data studio but there are some courses on the internet. you can learn from that.